# Suggestion about the poles around the mouth?

Tags: topology

I would like to know if this poles are good places? specialy near the mouth ? it is important to use Poles near the nose? [image]

Comment: Maybe the answer is to study what others have done. I know MakeHuman has done a lot of research into human figure topology, so you might start there.

Comment: One specific point of critique I can offer is: look up "nasolabial fold". I noticed your topology doesn't account for it, so it might result in unnatural looking smiles.